# Identifying a generic Hilbert space $H$ with an $L^2$ space on some measure space.

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, stochastic-integrals, malliavin-calculus

This may be a stupid question, but I was wondering, if we are given an
infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$, is it possible to find (or to
hypothesise that there's) a measure space $(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$ such
that $H$ coincides with $L^2(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$?

**Apparently this is a basic resultm and the answer is yes.**

---

Second question:

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, let  $W=\{W(h):h\in H\}$ be an isonormal Gaussian process, namely  a Gaussian Hilbert space indexed by $H$; then we know that $W=H^{:1:}$ (the first homogeneous chaos), and we further know that the stochastic Gaussian integral $I$ on a measure space $(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$  is an isometry from $L^2(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$ onto $H^{:1:}=W$.

Then any $W(h_i), h_i\in H$ can be represented as a stochastic Gaussian integral of some function in $L^2(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$, hence $W$ will be a Gaussian Hilbert space indexed by $L^2(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$.

My question is are $H$ and $L^2(M,\mathcal M,\mu)$ the same space?
If yes, the $W(\cdot)$ can be seen as a Gaussian stochatic integral.

Is it correct?

I may have made some mistakes on my reasoning, so if you spot something off please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not what you want, but take $M$ to be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Then $H\approx \ell^2(M)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an answer to your first question in the comments so let me address the second question. First I need to clean up some notation.

$H$ isn't itself a Gaussian Hilbert space so it seems incorrect to talk about the first homogeneous chaos over $H$. The situation is that the isonormal Gaussian process $W$ is an isometry $$H \to \tilde{W} = \tilde{W}^{\mathpunct: 1 \mathpunct:} = \operatorname{Ran}(W) \subseteq L^2(\Omega)$$ for some probability space $\Omega$ (Note I change some notation to avoid giving $W$ two definitions).

Now suppose we are given a linear isometry $I: L^2(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu) \to \tilde{W}$ (i.e. a Gaussian stochastic integral on $(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ into $\tilde{W}$). Note that this is an assumption and is not automatically true. What you get for free is that there is a Gaussian Hilbert space $V$ such that there is a Gaussian stochastic integral $$\tilde{I}:L^2(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu) \to V.$$
In general, it is not possible to assume $V = \tilde{W}$. A simple way to see this is to notice that $\tilde{W}$ may be finite dimensional whilst $L^2(M, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ may be infinite dimensional so that there can be no such isometry. However, for the sake of discussion, I suppose we are given such a Gaussian stochastic integral into $\tilde{W}$.

The next thing to notice is that $I$ need not be surjective. I assume you are still following "Gaussian Hilbert Spaces" by Svante Johnson. It's worth noting that when introducing Gaussian stochastic integrals he says that we can "assume without essential loss" that $I$ is surjective. He does this by noting that the range of $I$ is a Gaussian Hilbert space and we can hence just restrict the codomain. In the situation of this question however we have fixed the Gaussian Hilbert space $\tilde{W}$ and so can't restrict the codomain in this way. This means that even assuming there is a Gaussian stochastic integral into $\tilde{W}$, you don't get that $I: L^2(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu) \to \tilde{W}$ is surjective automatically. As an example of this, we may have that $H$ (and hence $\tilde{W}$) are infinite dimensional but $L^2(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu) = \mathbb{R}$ (take $M = \{0\}$ and $\mu = \delta_0$) so that $I$ cannot be surjective and also $H \not \approx L^2(M,\mathcal{M},\mu)$.

For the sake of further discussion, I will now assume that $I: L^2(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu) \to \tilde{W}$ is additionally surjective. Now the situation is simple. $W: H \to \tilde{W} \subseteq L^2(\Omega)$ is an isometric isomorphism, as is $I: L^2(M, \mathcal{M},\mu) \to \tilde{W}$. Hence $I^{-1} \circ W: H \to L^2(M,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is an isometric isomorphism. However, the assumptions we had to make to get here mean this is far from the generic situation.

Comment: Indeed the "H" in $H^{:1:}$ was for "H"omogeneous, I should have used $W^{:1:}$ for consistency with the notation.

Comment: Very clear and detailed, I now understand that all the steps I should do in order to end up with a situation like the one I proposed are not immediate and I need to do further assumptions. Indeed what I wanted to do is to reconcile the approach of Janson and the one from Nualart's book.

Comment: As you know Janson uses the concept of Gaussian Hilbert space indexed by a real Hilbert space, (the range of a Gaussian field); while Nualart uses the concept of Isonormal Gaussian process. I wanted to know if the components of the Isonormal Gaussian process could always be seen as a gaussian stochastic integral on some measure space.

Comment: I see. In that case you are allowed to choose the Measure space and so the commented answer to the first question is sufficient since it provides a measure space such that the desired properties  hold.